# Rails has_many through with condition, build new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I've got users and organisations with a join model UsersOrganisation.  Users may be admins of Organisations - if so the is_admin boolean is true.

If I set the is_admin boolean by hand in the database, Organisations.admins works as I'd expect.

In the console, I can do `Organisation.first.users << User.first` and it creates an organisations_users entry as I'd expect.

However if I do `Organisation.first.admins << User.last` it creates a normal user, not an admin, ie the is_admin boolean on the join table is not set correctly.

Is there a good way of doing this other than creating entries in the join table directly?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :organisations_users
  has_many :organisations, :through => :organisations_users

end

class Organisation <  ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :organisations_users
  has_many :users, :through => :organisations_users
  has_many :admins, :through => :organisations_users, :class_name => "User", 
            :source => :user, 
            :conditions => {:organisations_users => {:is_admin => true}}

end

class OrganisationsUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Comment: It sure that the `has_many :admins, :through => ... ...` will work for selection actually, not for inserting data. So when you are doing `Organisation.first.admin << User.last` it is just creating normal entries. However, Im wondering the same how to this. Thnx for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some twists with the `has_many :through` and the `<<` operator. But you could overload it like in @Erez answer.

My approach to this is using scopes (I renamed OrganisationsUsers to Memberships):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organisations, :through => :memberships

end

class Organisation <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :class_name => 'User', :source => :user

  # response to comment:
  def admins 
    memberships.admin
  end
end

class Memberships < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :user

  scope :admin, where(:is_admin => true)
end
```

Now I create new admins like this:

```
Organisation.first.memberships.admin.create(:user => User.first)
```

What I like about the scopes is that you define the "kind of memberships" in the membership class, and the organisation itself doesn't have to care about the kinds of memberships at all.

**Update**:

Now you can do

`Organisation.first.admins.create(:user => User.first)`

Comment: Is there any way you can make this do `Organisation.first.admins.create(:user => User.first)`

Comment: yes if you make a small alias in the Organisation model (see my edited answer)

Comment: I have ended up making a nested form for the join table, but I've accepted this answer as it answers my question very clearly.

Answer (score 5):

You can always override the << method of the association:

```
has_many :admins do

  def <<(user)
    user.is_admin = true
    self << user
  end

end
```

(Code has not been checked)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code for organization model.

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :organisations_users
  has_many :organisations_admins, :class_name => "OrganisationsUser", :conditions => { :is_admin => true }

  has_many :users,  :through => :organisations_users
  has_many :admins, :through => :organisations_admins, :source => :user

end
```

Comment: Much prefer this method since it also solves the assignment issues.